# Uploading image in database and file directory codeigniter

Tags: file, codeigniter, upload

this is my controller main.php  this is uploading the file in directory what i want to store the same file name in database and retrieve the image by name. you can tell be the solution code or edit my code really need the code

```
<?php

       class Main extends CI_controller{ // mian controller

            function index(){
           $this->load->view('main_view.php', array('error'=>''));

                            }
            function upload(){ // upload function for image



                         $config['upload_path'] = './images/'; //directory
                         $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';//type allow
                         $this->load->library('upload',$config);

                            if(! $this->upload->do_upload()){

                            $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
                            $this->load->view('main_view',$error);
                                                              }
                                  else
                                        {
        // 

                                     $file_data = $this->upload->data();
                                     $data['img'] = base_url().'/images/'. $file_data['file_name'] ;
                                     $this->load->view('success_msg',$data);



                                         }
                                                    }

                             }
 ?>
```

this is my view main_view.php

```
 <html>
    <body>

       <? echo $error;?>

       <? echo form_open_multipart('main/upload'); ?>
           <input type="file" name="userfile" />
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
             <?php echo form_close();?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i want to upload file name in database and can easily retrieve the image

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the image name wth: `$this->upload->file_name`

EDIT:

there are some errors in your code.

1) this `$this->load->view('main_view.php', array('error'=>''));`should be `$this->load->view('main_view', array('error'=>''));`without the .php extension.

2) `CI_controller` should be `CI_Controller`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple lines of code to upload a file in a folder and grab the file name and store it in database.

```php
$image_path = '../../test_images/'.$_FILES['question_image']['name'];

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['question_image']['tmp_name']))
{
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['question_image']['tmp_name'], $image_path) ;  
}           

$image_url = "test_images/".$_FILES['question_image']['name'];
```

$image_path is the url where you want to upload your file and $image_url will contain  the url that your are going to store into database

Now you can retrieve the image by

```php
<img src="<?base_url($image_url)?>" />
```

Comment: He already uploaded the image with the correct class of CodeIgniter.